# How do i add a column with the crew name according to date_time?

Tags: python, sql, excel

This is the situation:

- There is a warehouse that operates 24/7.
- It has 3 Crews, working on 2 shifts- Crew 1, 2 and 3.
- The Shift System works like this:

  *7 x 3* - work 7 days and rest 3 days.
  *7 x 4* - work 7 nights and rest 4 days.
- Day shifts Start on Tuesday at 6:00, working everyday from 6:00 - 18:00 and finishing the next Monday.
- Night shifts Start on Friday at 18:00, working everynight from 18:00 and finishing the next Friday at 6:00

**Example:**

1. Crew 2 begins it´s shift on tuesday 7/12/2022 from 6:00 to 18:00.
2. Crew 3 replaces Crew 2 staring at 18:00 to 6:00, this happens while Crew 3 is resting

   ...
3. On Friday 7/15/2022 Crew 1 replaces Crew 3 in the night shift.
4. On Monday 7/18/2022 Crew 2 goes to rest and its counterpart (Crew 3) replaces them starting a new shift on 7/19/2022

I have a query which gives me all the transactions in any given date, i already have the column if it´s a day or night shift thing on my table

| Item ID | Qty Picked | Date Timestamp | Crew |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12503 | 3 | 14/1/2022 8:02:36 AM | ? |
| 98565 | 8 | 14/1/2022 7:10:36 PM | ? |
| 14158 | 14 | 15/1/2022 3:02:36 AM | ? |

I need to fill the column `Crew` with their respective code (1, 2, 3) depending on the timestamp when the transaction happened.

Any Excel, MYSQL or Python help will be appreciated.

I know this is looong lol,thank you for reading, it is an interesting mathematical problem IMO.

Comment: What SQL product (mySQL, Oracle, SQL Server, etc.)

Comment: Hey, It is MYSQL, I just edited the post, thanks.